# hstore pql 9.3, rails 4.0.3 storing as symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

Really confused here, I thought hstore stores the keys and values as strings, yet I am not getting that in console. It's storing them as a hash, take a look:

```
2.0.0-p247 :003 > a = Report.new
=> #<Report id: nil, name: nil, column_data: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :004 > a.column_data = {key: {yes: true}, value: 'hello'}
=> {:key=>{:yes=>true}, :value=>"hello"} 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > a
=> #<Report id: nil, name: nil, column_data: {:key=>{:yes=>true}, :value=>"hello"}, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :006 > a.column_data[:key][:yes]
=> true 
2.0.0-p247 :007 > a.column_data[:key]
=> {:yes=>true}
```

Is something I am doing wrong or is this the new way now?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried saving and reloading `a` before accessing the `hstore`?

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. Thanks!